# Hide dot on unordered list

Tags: html, list, css

I am trying to customise an unordered list, which is used of for the navigation menu on this site: http://chaine-charlotte.org/

You'll see there is a dot/disc between each menu item, running horizontally along the header. I'd like to remove the dot.

I don't have direct access to the CSS code (as far as I can ascertain) as it's a wordpress.com site (I've only ever dealt with wordpress.org self-hosted sites until now). Otherwise, I would post it.

Of course, I can inspect elements from the user/browser side, but so far I've failed to identify which CSS declaration is generating the dot/disc, and therefore which to apply one or both of the following to:

```
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
```

Can someone please inspect the site from the front end, and kindly tell me which CSS property I should be customising with these declarations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add css:

```
.nav-menu > li > a::before {
    content: "";
}
```

Because following css is making the dot.

```
.nav-menu > li > a::before {
    color: #fff;
    content: " •";
    margin-right: 1em;
    opacity: 0.15;
}
```

Comment: I've spent the better part of an hour trying to figure this out. Thank you so much. Would it be possible to tell me how you identified it was that particular bit of CSS (`.nav-menu > li > a::before {` or is that going to be complex to explain in writing? Obviously my approach was inadequate.

Comment: @inspiredlife You can easily findout by inspecting element on anchor tag. And most of dot and other symbol are used on li using content and before.  Learn content here. https://css-tricks.com/css-content/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/

Comment: I've read over (and taken a note of) those articles. Thanks. What tool did you use to identify `.nav-menu > li > a::before {` as the selector creating the dot? I have been using the Web Developer tools Inspector in Firefox, and don't see it. I've also used Firebug in Firefox, and failed to locate it.

Comment: @inspiredlife Yeah i am using same for it. Here i can identify. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0ff.png

Comment: Finally figured it out. I just hadn't dug deep enough into the tree of html (which is all collapsed by default in Web Developer Tools inspector. Because I originally didn't realise it was the <a> tag I needed to address. Thanks for the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It is from below css

```
.nav-menu > li > a:before {
 color: #fff;
 content: ' \2022';
 margin-right: 1em;
 opacity: .15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

It isn't a dot in the `ul`, that's why your code doesn't work. The anchors in the menu have a [before selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), which insert a char *(a dot)* before each one.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arglab/eqc3kkht/)

```css
q::before { 
  content: "«";
  color: blue;
}
q::after { 
  content: "»";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<q> That's how before and after work </q>
```

Check `li > a:before`

**Solution**

Add this to your CSS

```
.nav-menu > li > a::before {
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks arglab. I appreciate the explanation. My limited experience with CSS has not involved before and after selectors until now. I should point out that applying the code you have suggested as a fix does not have any effect. However, applying the code from ketan had the desired result right away.

Comment: @inspiredlife you're right, sorry, I was asleep. I edited the post