# Using javascript to target a parent with css

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I'm still very new and learning but I'm trying to get a personal project finished with so I'm on here to look for an elegant solution.
Think of this project like a 'toDo' list. I have multiple lists with a checkbox, when the checkbox is `:checked`, I need it to change the `background-color` of the parent `li` container.

But also, at the top of the page I have a checkbox to hide all the completed tasks, which is the `li` containers with a completed (`:checked`) child.
From what I have read, this isn't possible purely with CSS as you can't select parent of a style. However my knowledge of JavaScript is too limited to be able to understand how to make a solution myself or repurpose many solutions similar problems I have seen on here. I can't find one that will pass a style to `display: none;` as a toggle.

I'm looking for a pure JS (jQuery free) solution, for simplicity sake.

The 'hide completed tasks' checkbox should toggle all completed tasks on or off with `display: none` / `display: flow;`, the individual task checkbox should just change the parent `li` background color.

```css
/*this rule hides all task. I want to only hide the task which are :checked*/

#hide-toggle1:checked~* .task1 {
  display: none;
}


/*this css rule hides only the checked input. I need it to hide the whole <li>*/

#hide-toggle2:checked~* .task2>input:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle1">
  <label for="hide-toggle1">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-1" value="0">
      <label for="1-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-2" value="0">
      <label for="1-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-3" value="0">
      <label for="1-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle2">
  <label for="hide-toggle2">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-1" value="0">
      <label for="2-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-2" value="0">
      <label for="2-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-3" value="0">
      <label for="2-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have a way to backtrack up the element tree. You can't target an element based on its children.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend learning some `javascript`, it will make your life A LOT easier. I wrote this code in the most basic form to try to help you understand it better. I also tried to comment what I was doing. I added an `'check-input'` class to each input in the lists and a `'hide-list'` class to the hide buttons.

```js
// Add an event to each 'input' tag
function AddEventListeners() {
  // get all items marked with a class 'check-input'
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('check-input');
  // whatever background color you want the 'li' to turn once checked
  let desiredBackgroundColor = "green";
  // loop through all input elements
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // add the event listener for a 'click'
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // get the parent element which would be the 'li'
      let li_parent = this.parentElement;
      // set its background color to transparent if it has already been clicked
      if (li_parent.style.backgroundColor == desiredBackgroundColor) {
        li_parent.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      } else {
        if (this.checked == true) {
          li_parent.style.backgroundColor = desiredBackgroundColor;
        } else {
          li_parent.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // get all buttons marked by a class 'hide-list'
  let hideButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-list');
  // add a pressed state variable to see when the button has been pressed
  let pressed = false;
  // loop through all hide buttons
  for (let i = 0; i < hideButtons.length; i++) {
    // add the event listener
    hideButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // get the 'li' marked with 'task' and their number, either 1 or 2
      let children_li = document.getElementsByClassName('task' + (i + 1));

      // check if the button has already been pressed
      if (pressed == true) {
        for (let j = 0; j < children_li.length; j++) {
          // if it has, make the elements visible again
          children_li[j].style.display = "block";
        }
        pressed = false;
        return;
      }
      pressed = true;
      for (let j = 0; j < children_li.length; j++) {
        // if the elements have been marked by the background color, make them invisible
        if (children_li[j].style.backgroundColor == desiredBackgroundColor) {
          children_li[j].style.display = "none";
        } else {
          children_li[j].style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="AddEventListeners();">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle1" class="hide-list">
  <label for="hide-toggle1">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-1" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="1-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-2" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="1-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-3" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="1-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle2" class="hide-list">
  <label for="hide-toggle2">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-1" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="2-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-2" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="2-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-3" value="0" class="check-input">
      <label for="2-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

For some good and free JS tutorials, I would recommend

https://www.sololearn.com/learning

and / or

https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Just a useful topic if your interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395468/hide-dot-on-unordered-list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using common classes: for hide checkbox: `hideall el` and for your list items : `task el`
This way you add event `addEventListener` to all check-boxes with class `el`.

From there you check if clicked item has class `hideall` or `task`.

If its `task` and its `checked` add green to its parent `li` element.

If its `hideall`, grab all next `ul's` checked `li's` and hide...

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".el").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    if (event.target.classList.contains('task') && event.target.checked) {
      event.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "green";} else {
      event.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = ""}

    if (event.target.classList.contains('hideall')) {
      let e = event.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll(".task:checked");
      
      event.target.checked ? e.forEach(li => {li.parentElement.style.display = "none"
      }) : e.forEach(li => {li.parentElement.style.display = "flow"; li.parentElement.classList.add("dot")})
    }
  });
})
```

```css
/*this will bring missing dot afte show hide back*/

.dot::before {
    color: black;
    content: "•  ";
    margin-left: -13px;
    padding-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle1" class="hideall el">
  <label for="hide-toggle1">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-1" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="1-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-2" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="1-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1-3" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="1-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-toggle2" class="hideall el">
  <label for="hide-toggle2">Hide completed tasks</label>
  <ul>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-1" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="2-1">Task 1</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-2" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="2-2">Task 2</label>
    </li>
    <li class="task2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2-3" value="0" class="task el">
      <label for="2-3">Task 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```